# Cheapest way to host azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

What is the cheapest way to host azure functions and do a pay as you go.

I am looking to host one or two functions that are available quickly, but will only be called a few times a day. The functions will read from some type of storage(files) and return data from that storage to the caller.

What is the cheapest way to host azure functions in azure with access to some type of storage?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to host your function with [Consumption plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan), you just need to pay only when your functions are running.

> Billing is based on number of executions, execution time, and memory used. Billing is aggregated across all functions within a function app.